# Bootstrap 3, 2 column fluid container with container structure

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a `container-fluid` container that has a two column structure for background color/image needs which contains a `container` class. The container class is there as an attempt for the content to align with non `container-fluid` class containers. That alignment with a full width column structure for two background colors is my goal.

Here is a visual example of what I'm trying to create. 
[image]

See my code below to see my attempt so far...

```css
.flex { display: flex; }

.container-fluid { background: #fff; }
  .container-fluid .col-sm-6:last-of-type { background: #000; color: #fff; }

  .container-fluid .container { width: initial; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>This is a container class. The content below should align with this containers content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex">
  
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h4>Column 1</h4>
            <p>This content needs to align with the container class above.</p> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-0">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h4>Column 2</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your final requirement screenshot aswell?

Comment: @Nitheesh Updated with an image.

Comment: do you need to keep the code layout same? Can i make modifications to the class names?

Comment: If you want alignment then wrap all of the content with the `container` class? Also you can use the `card` class.

Answer (score 1):

Each `row` class adds a `-15px` `margin-left` and `margin-right` also each `col-*` class classes adds a `15px` `padding-left` and `padding-right`. These needs to be matched correctly. I have also removing the offset classes that seems to add a misalignment. Please add that back if you need the same. Hope this solution works for you.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.container-fluid {
  background: #fff;
}
.container-fluid .col-sm-6:last-of-type {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.container-fluid .container {
  width: initial;
}
```

```html
<link
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>
        This is a container class. The content below should align with this
        containers content.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6">
      <div class="row container">
        <h4>Column 1</h4>
        <p>
          This content needs to align with the container class above.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6">
      <div class="container row">
        <h4>Column 2</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close, but not exactly what I'm going for. The image doesn't represent this well, but I'm looking for the content not to break 1366px width but allow the full bleed of the background colors. Does that makes sense to you?

Comment: Another example would be change the first container-fluid back to a container and then the content inside the container fluid should align to the first container width while the backgrounds bleed to the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your bootrstrap css path with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
```